# How can I extract keys of an object to a type while enforcing the values?

Tags: typescript

I want to define a constant object that has a fixed value type, then extract its keys to a separate type:

```js
interface Foo {
  name: string;
}

interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: Foo;
}

const myObject: MyObject = {
  a: {name: 'this is a'},
  b: {name: 'this is b'},
}

type Keys = keyof typeof myObject;
```

This example doesn't currently work, cause `typeof myObject` resolves to `MyObject`, which has `key` of type `string`. If I don't type `myObject` to `MyObject`, then it correctly resolves `Keys` to `"a" | "b"`. However, then it will no longer enforce that all the values are valid instances of `Foo`.

Is there any way for me to have my cake and eat to *without* having to predefine `Keys` as an enum and using it to define `MyObject`?

Example of what I'd like to avoid:

```
type Keys = "a" | "b"

interface MyObject {
  [key in Keys]: Foo;
}

const myObject: MyObject = {
  a: {name: 'this is a'},
  b: {name: 'this is b'},
}
```

(because I don't want to have to update both `Keys` and `myObject` every time I add or remove a key.

Comment: This is a really good question! the closest I can come with at the moment is leaving it inferred, but using a type assertion. Which isn't exactly what you want here, but it does prevent compilation in case of an error. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7JHAWwgC5kBnMKUAc2QF8AoB0SWRFAWQE8B5AIwBWEBGBwNkyANoBrCF1IUqIagF1SGdAG4GjBgnQgKyAlwDimACb8hI5AF4xEuKVz4ipAORgAFsDLI-ZDgPegAacWQ+FzxCEmQvX39AvhC6cMYAegzkAEEyMmhRYDAPf2pLADoGE3N0K0FhUTh-bmtGpn1DURMAITh6m1EHbAjnHAk0iKjxvn6AOVjPH0Dk1PSGLNz8woCSssrqrj6BxqCW3gaRIA)